# How can I improve mobile rendering performance on pages with many images?

Tags: seo, wordpress, google-pagespeed

I'm helping a client improve SEO performance on a WordPress blog where the posts typically include complex magazine-style layouts with text flowing around large images. The images are all webp and I've set up LiteSpeed Cache which works great to optimize css + js. I've used lazy image loading where appropriate.

( example post: https://www.janetjay.com/inspiring-quotes-about-invisible-illness/ )

The complex posts load near-instantly on desktop and Pagespeed Insights routinely gives me a 98-100 performance score on desktop. But mobile performance (according to Pagespeed insights) is awful, with LCP times of 5+ seconds. My sense is that's because the mobile browser has to do a ton of work to parse those complex layouts onto a narrow screen.

Testing the site as a user, I don't really notice these delays. The top part of the page renders quickly, the slow-rendering parts are further down the page, people can read the opening paragraphs right away. But I'm concerned the low Performance number on Pagespeed Insights will hurt page ranking.

I'm in the process of getting set up with a CDN but I'm not sure that would make a difference in this case.

Are there other things I can try?

Comment: Can you share the URL?

Comment: added example url to the post

Answer (score 3):

Website speed is a factor as you noted, it appears to load fast; it would be nice if Pagespeed showed the same results to confirm that but Google does not actually use the value provided by Pagespeed or any available tool, but Google suggests using them to improve a sites speed...

[image]

I'm seeing just over 1.5 seconds with the delay being 1.2 seconds of scripting until rendering and painting. So it is not the network speed it is the script.

> Correction, the scripting speed on my side is because I've got
> extensions running to look at the schema, it is not the site it is my
> browser.

But, more important than page speed for YMYL is Google trust/EAT/EEAT.

### YMYL

The site appears to be in the topical category of YMYL, "Your Money, Your Life," is mostly an E-A-T, "Expertise, Authority, and Trust," with E-E-A-T being another algo added to find the hidden gems, (the extra "E" is for the author's Expertise, so an "author" signal may improve EAT SEO on other sites).

The knowledge graph seems to be the best way to get a view of this type of Google data. And a solid Knowledge Panel works for YMYL topics.

Knowledge graph https://developers.google.com/knowledge-graph/reference/rest/v1?apix_params=%7B%22query%22%3A%22janet%20jay%22%7D

gives me.

```
{
  "@context": {
    "@vocab": "http://schema.org/",
    "resultScore": "goog:resultScore",
    "detailedDescription": "goog:detailedDescription",
    "goog": "http://schema.googleapis.com/",
    "kg": "http://g.co/kg",
    "EntitySearchResult": "goog:EntitySearchResult"
  },
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "resultScore": 542.8009033203125,
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Thing"
        ],
        "@id": "kg:/g/121bq6zf",
        "name": "Jay Kyle"
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11ggm0wnkf",
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      },
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11sscgxq9p",
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11pxyx7tk3",
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      },
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11v4_0p8zp",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      },
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11hcv1n51x",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11tg0lj0lj"
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11v4xjsydc",
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11qncd5ytn",
        "@type": [
          "Person",
          "Thing"
        ]
      },
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "result": {
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11h205ndr7",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "@id": "kg:/g/11kt1wnwlv",
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      },
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11v5wwbwqp"
      }
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "@id": "kg:/g/11f4_hgqlw"
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11tc5_d4y_",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11k4rpvd95",
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11k3fw6m_v",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      },
      "resultScore": 24
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "@id": "kg:/g/11kj2sd0kp",
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      },
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult"
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@id": "kg:/g/11sdw9_gw2"
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "resultScore": 24,
      "result": {
        "@id": "kg:/g/11v78kcnn0",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "name": "Janet Jay"
      }
    },
    {
      "resultScore": 24,
      "@type": "EntitySearchResult",
      "result": {
        "name": "Janet Jay",
        "@type": [
          "Person"
        ],
        "@id": "kg:/g/11rbfn_ykr"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Several of these seem to relate to Janet,

https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/g/11k3fw6m_v would include the pinterest
https://www.google.com/search?kgmid=/g/11v5wwbwqp#ip=1 lists the site first but does not show the claim knowledge panel. I'ld expect the one associated with the website to show the website in the panel and if nothing else exists show the claim option under it.

> You don't need an address to have a panel, but to claim it you need to
> Prove your identity which normally requires an address. I'm looking for the panel that would come up when somebody searches for a site.

So I'm not certain what ID Google has for Janet as an online [person, organization]? Google may not be certain because it does not see a verifiable signal to create update the record to say this unique person with this global ID is part of this unique website with this unique ID.

### The @person, @profile record?

The schema on her home page to find the correct profile ...

```
[{
    "@context": "https://schema.org",
    "@graph": [
        {
            "@type": "CollectionPage",
            "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/",
            "url": "https://www.janetjay.com/",
            "name": "Janet Jay",
            "isPartOf": {
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#website"
            },
            "about": {
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#/schema/person/49fd663595967a28dc8ecae0d225b471"
            },
            "description": "I've been in pain for the majority of my life, much of it with no diagnosis. I'm sharing my experiences and observations in the hope that it'll help you skip some of the BS I went through... and maybe feel a little less alone.",
            "breadcrumb": {
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#breadcrumb"
            },
            "inLanguage": "en-US"
        },
        {
            "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
            "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#breadcrumb",
            "itemListElement": [
                {
                    "@type": "ListItem",
                    "position": 1,
                    "name": "Home"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "@type": "WebSite",
            "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#website",
            "url": "https://www.janetjay.com/",
            "name": "Pain: Chronic / Words: Iconic",
            "description": "",
            "publisher": {
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#/schema/person/49fd663595967a28dc8ecae0d225b471"
            },
            "alternateName": "JanetJay.com",
            "potentialAction": [
                {
                    "@type": "SearchAction",
                    "target": {
                        "@type": "EntryPoint",
                        "urlTemplate": "https://www.janetjay.com/?s={search_term_string}"
                    },
                    "query-input": "required name=search_term_string"
                }
            ],
            "inLanguage": "en-US"
        },
        {
            "@type": [
                "Person",
                "Organization"
            ],
            "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#/schema/person/49fd663595967a28dc8ecae0d225b471",
            "name": "Janet Jay",
            "image": {
                "@type": "ImageObject",
                "inLanguage": "en-US",
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#/schema/person/image/",
                "url": "https://www.janetjay.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/IMG_0020-1.jpg",
                "contentUrl": "https://www.janetjay.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/IMG_0020-1.jpg",
                "width": 952,
                "height": 952,
                "caption": "Janet Jay"
            },
            "logo": {
                "@id": "https://www.janetjay.com/#/schema/person/image/"
            },
            "description": "The TLDR is that I’ve been in constant pain since I was 15. Nobody knew why, and I didn’t get any kind of a valid diagnosis until my late 20s/early 30s. I’ve spent the majority of my life in pain and have spent 20 years learning to talk the doctor talk and walk the medical walk. That’s why I’m thrilled to get the opportunity to help others avoid some of the pitfalls. Stay tuned to this space for all the doctor tips and tricks I’ve spent most of my life discovering, and some of the feels and fears I’ve uncovered as well.",
            "sameAs": [
                "https://www.janetjay.com",
                "https://facebook.com/pain.chronic.words.iconic",
                "https://instagram.com/pain.chronic_words.iconic",
                "https://www.linkedin.com/in/janetjay/",
                "https://pinterest.com/Janet_Jay_dotcom",
                "https://twitter.com/https://twitter.com/janetkjay",
                "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRMw0K14G8N2-KHuDiNQrtw"
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

If I'm reading the schema correctly ... "@type": [
"Person",
"Organization"
] I can not find the "URL": "https://www.janetjay.com/about/". Also some trust signals are missing. the

```
"memberOf": {
    "@type": "Orgainastion",
    "URL": "https://uspainfoundation.org/about-us/our-team/"
}
```

Needs to be under the @person record and linked from the about page (already is linked) so it can be included in Janet's Google Knowledge Panel.

Can these records be consolidated? Maybe the About page should be the best location for the full @person record or profile to build the knowledge panel. Sadly Google My Business does not have an Author's business section to use ... so it is all schema to build the panel.

> Almost all schema, A Wikipedia page or wikidata page also is enough of
> a signal if that is possible.

Tell Janet thank you for her efforts to give people a better quality of life.

Comment: Hey @Wayne this is terrific info, thanks so much for the detailed response. This will take me a while to digest but it's already illuminating.

Comment: @BunnyBlake wish I had an easier answer, schema while a simply concept is complicated when it comes to filling out all of the information an organizing it. Most people just upload content and say, "let google figure it out." With schema we are figuring it out pro-actively and creating the signal. Numerous people have documented their schema people methods with success ... looks like site:uspainfoundation.org also needs a knowledge panel they may be able to use "google my business" to create one as they have an address.

Comment: If uspainfoundation has been covered by a newspaper for a topic relating to pain, that information can be placed in Wikipedia for that topic and would allow uspainfoundation to have a Wikipedia page to explain who they are ...

Comment: correction uspainfoundation has a panel. https://www.google.com/search?q=uspainfoundation&rlz=1CALAYK_enUS984US984&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8 but contact information (contact as in Janet Jay) is not yet on their panel.